# Opposite of "Extend Selection?"

Tags: front-end, keyboard

I am trying to become more proficient with Mathematica shortcuts.

To avoid using the mouse when folding a section, I am using Extend Selection `CTRL+.`. I press that key until the whole section is highlighted and then fold the section with `CTRL+'`. However, when doing so, I often press the key one too many times, also selecting the parent section above.

Is there a command that is the opposite of Extend Selection? I have tried to look through the keyboard shortcuts but could not find it. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Without a history of how the selection was extended, there would be an ambiguity in how to contract a selection.  (But maybe there's such a command.)

Comment: Perhaps selecting with ```SHIFT+UpArrow```, unselecting with ```SHIFT+DownArrow``` ?